# Checking isomorphism between two measure preserving maps

Tags: measure-theory, ergodic-theory

Let $T_1\colon [0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]$ be the full tent map, $B_1$ be the collection of Borel sets, and $m_1$ denote the Lebesgue measure. Let $T_2\colon\sum_2^+\rightarrow \sum_2^+$ be the full one sided shift map on two symbols, $B_2$ be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by cylinder sets and $m_2$ be the $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$ product measure. Are $T_1$ and $T_2$ isomorphic and why?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What do you call the "full" tent map ? Does this discussion provide your answer http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99782/measure-theoretic-entropy-of-general-tent-maps ?

Comment: By full tent map I mean the following map: $T:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]$ given by $T(x)=1-|2x-1|$.

Comment: So this is the case $\alpha=\frac12$ in the link I gave above and it answers your question, don't it ?

Comment: Yes I guess it does, thank you Stephane.